# Why is Q → P a logical consequence of ¬(P → Q )

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory

I don't want to ask my professor about this because I'm awful at this and he's not the, uhh, *patient* type of professor to say the least.

Anyhow, it was my understanding that `¬(P → Q)` and `(¬P → ¬Q)` mean two different things.
And that `Q → P` is equal to `(¬P → ¬Q)`.

Yet one of the answers to a question says that `Q → P` is a logical consequence of `¬(P → Q)`, which I just don't understand at all.

To confuse matters further, afaik `¬(p → q) ⟺ p ∧ ¬q` is correct, so I guess I'm just lost and missing something here in the definition of logical consequence?

Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. This is for a Reasoning class that's part of a Philosophy minor, but I figured this is probably the best place to ask!

Comment: I'm sure, you have seen that $P\to Q \iff \neg P \vee Q$. So we have $\neg(P \to Q) \iff \neg(\neg P \vee Q) \iff P \wedge \neg Q \Rightarrow P \vee \neg Q \iff Q \to P$.

Comment: If $P$ holds, then so does $Q \rightarrow P$ (more generally, if $P$ holds then the implication $X \rightarrow P$ holds for any $X$). You already know that $\neg (P \rightarrow Q)$ is equivalent to $P \wedge \neg Q$, and the latter holds if $P$ and $\neg Q$ both hold. So if $\neg (P \rightarrow Q)$ holds, then so does $P$. In turn, so does $Q \rightarrow P$.

Comment: @Z.A.K. Is the statement $X \rightarrow P$ equivalent to the assertion that "P is vacuously true"? If so, I find it more intuitive (reading left to right) to [re-]phrase the statement as "$P \leftarrow X$" paired with the explanation that "$Q⊣X$" (i.e., the particular claim of "Q" is definitionally entailed by "some *anything* claim" i.e. "$Q$ is true iff arbitrary_$X$ is true").

Comment: @Botanicus  Your intermediary steps from "$¬(¬P∨Q)$" to "$Q \rightarrow P$" are, although seemingly technically accurate (since evidently, there be no specification of causation in the single-bar arrow connectives in this form of logic), slightly misleading. The important aspect seems to be [the assumption ]that "$P∧¬Q.$" ⊨ "$P.$".

Comment: As you observed, $\neg(P\rightarrow Q)$ is equivalent to $P \land \neg Q$, which implies $P$. But then everything implies $P$, even $False$, as $P$ is true. $P \rightarrow (Q\rightarrow P)$ is a tautology.

Comment: I came back to this question just to let everyone know that, against all odds, I passed my Logic class with an 85/100! Everyone's explanations here really helped me look at logic problems from another perspective so I feel like I owe you all a huge thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer posted after a previous one was accepted.)

Don't feel bad. It's a tricky little exercise in so-called vacuous truth. The last $P$ could have been any proposition whatsoever, say $R$ as in this truth table.

[image]

Sourse: https://www.erpelstolz.at/gateway/TruthTable.html

This result can also be formally obtained using a form of natural deduction and proof by contradiction as follows (screenshot from my proof checker)

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for this addition, it really helped me understand the logic behind it better. And the truth table example and link is super useful!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $Q$.

Suppose $P$. We can conclude $Q$. Therefore, $P \to Q$. But we also know that $\neg (P \to Q)$. Contradiction. Everything follows from a contradiction; therefore, we can conclude $P$.

Thus, we have shown that $Q \to P$. $\square$

Phrasing the proof differently, we can show $\neg Q$ is a logical consequence of $\neg (P \to Q)$. Since $Q$ is false, $Q \to P$ is automatically true.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense; I think I was getting too hung up about the semantics of "consequence" to just consider the proof. Still can't believe I walked into a math class by picking philosophy. Thanks a lot for the help, appreciate it!

Comment: @DanielK. No problem. Math and philosophy both have valuable perspectives on logic, and I think it's valuable for both mathematicians and philosophers to look at the other side's contributions.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree, I'm honestly just sulking because I seemingly have no natural talent for it. Even so, I really quite enjoy math and it's nice to see a philosophy minor actually include this fundamental type of stuff.

Comment: @DanielK. Don't sweat it. Not being able to shoot a basket when you start learning basketball feels discouraging, since it's such a simple element of the game. But everyone starts out not knowing how to do it. You'll get there eventually.

Comment: @Mark Saving  Would your "phrasing the proof differently" mode amount to an argument other than proof-by-contradiction?, whereas your preceding proof is indeed a proof-by-contradiction? Is "automatically true" analogous to object-level "vacuously true", translatable as "[necessarily ]not(not-false)"?

Comment: @11qq00 Neither proof is a proof by contradiction. Proof by contradiction is when one proves a statement $R$ by showing $\neg \neg R$. Both proofs use the fact that anything follows from a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

To say that $$B \text{ is a logical consequence of } A$$ is to say that $$A \text{ logically entails } (\models)\: B.$$

Claim: $$¬(P → Q) \quad \models \quad Q → P$$

A proof: \begin{align}&¬(P → Q)
\\\equiv\:& ¬(¬P \lor Q)
\\\equiv\:& P \land ¬Q
\\\models\:& ¬Q \lor P
\\\equiv\:& Q → P.
\end{align}

Comment: Going from $¬(¬P∨Q)$ to $P∧¬Q$ is a wee bit of a stretch, in a similar way that deriving $Q∨¬P$ from the not-*strictly*-equivalent $P→Q$ is: the former (used in determining this_Ans ↤Q) moves from a presumed degree of truth that is not-necessarily-vacuous to a (lesser) one that *is*-necessarily-vacuous, the latter the other direction. Then again, afaik  non-causal iff (if-and-only-if: $↔$) and logical-and are the only binary connective forms purely of ponens for validity (to be necessarily true). Whereas $⦗□(¬⟮P→Q⟯⦘≣⦗□(¬⟮¬P⟯∨Q⦘≣⦗□(P∧⟮¬Q⟯)⦘⇒P\&¬Q$ and similarly $⦗P⥽Q⦘≣⦗□(P→Q)⦘≣⦗□(Q∨⟮¬P⟯)⦘$,..

Comment: (cont'd).. removing necessitation at any stage alters the chain (and potentially its validity): semantically $Q→P$ is little more than a tautology when viewed as a ‘consequence’ of $\operatorname{opposite}∘(P→Q)$. which is consistent iff viewing the not-operator as negation rather than nullification. ..

Comment: Since they are two different concepts, in a case where the relevant information extracted must be the same (such as a dyadic truth value, in this example), basic equivalence ($≡$) still holds (with the relation [$⊤⩒⊥$] in the background; an equivalentness analogue to equality⦗$=$⦘) and moreover is more appropriate here since the identicalness analogue of equality ($≣$) does not.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Dan Christensen's answer, it's interesting to note that

$\neg(P\rightarrow Q) \rightarrow (R \rightarrow P)$

is also a tautology.

So the second Q could have been any proposition whatsoever, like R.